# getting error during selenium automation selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

[i need to click second row submit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDudL.png)I am trying to use the XPath of the tab present on the website and collected XPath using chrome/firefox but it seems that every time I am getting an exception as below:

I have kept sleep time and can see website loading pretty early than the sleep time still getting the errors.

```py
 said_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder3Col_txtSubmitCase"]')
 print(said_input)
 said_input.send_keys(said)

exception:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder3Col_txtSubmitCase"]
```

One thing is that i have navigated to another page of website by clicking one of the menu button will this driver.find_element_by_xpath will be able to locate it. if not how can i do so in case if i hae to browse through multiple pages and fill few forms.

Comment: can you please share what you are trying to interact with? what website and what specific element on the page

Comment: Most likely the problem is that the id is generated dynamically and you need to match only on its part or find another unique static identifier of this element. `HTML` with the element would be helpful.

Comment: No the ID or xpath i have validated number of time and it is same[static].